# Send link (or other) such that form is already filled out

Tags: forms

Is there a way to send some a url (or other thing) to a site such that data in a form is already filled out? This is not to my own site that I control.

For example, I want to send a link to some airline flights and want to have the destination and date be automatically filled out when the link is opened.

I'm guessing not, but have gotten lucky here before :) Maybe with some kind of program or add-on or??

Comment: Thus would depend entirely on the site you're linking to.  There's no accepted universal way of sending that kind of information.

Comment: A browser extension may be able to pre-fill the form using Javascript, like the way 1Password auto-fills login information.

Comment: Do you know how 1Password works? This does seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If its written with GET method so just try to play with the site and just put the url with all the args you found.

If it is POST, so you need to create an add-on or pretend to a browser, search the net for this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, if the remote site is not ready for that.